# Is there a way to retrieve specific string values using slicing and indexing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, indexing, slice

I am trying to retrieve the username and domain from a user email address.

For example: john.smith@apple.com

```
username = john.smith    
domain = apple
```

I am trying to remove the ".com" from being printed to the console. Note, other email addresses could account for different endings such as ".ca", ".org" , etc.

I also know I can use the .partition() method, however, I am trying to accomplish this with slicing and indexing.

Here is some code I have written so far:

```
mail = input("Enter email address: ")

username = email.find("@")
domain = email.find("@")

print("Username: " + email[:username])

print("Domain: " + email[domain+1:])
```

Output:

```
Enter email address: john.smith@apple.com
Username: john.smith
Domain: apple.com
```

Goal:

```
Enter email address: john.smith@apple.com
Username: john.smith
Domain: apple
```

Is there a way **(only through indexing and slicing)** that I can account for any amount of chars a user inputs to console, and remove the ".com" or ".ca", thus, only displaying the main name in the domain? Am I on the right track with finding the "@" and then slicing it from there?

Comment: `final = email.rfind(".")`, then `print("Domain: " + email[domain+1:final])`. However this is generally a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Are you allowed to use .split("@") then split('.') ?

Comment: @Malo this problem is to be solved with slicing and using .find() only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already demonstrated every technique you should use to solve this.  You already divided the full string at the addend; now do the same for the dot in the address:

```
domain = email[domain+1:]     # "apple.com"
dot = domain.find(`.`)        # Get position of the dot ...
company = domain[:dot]        #   and take everything up to that position.
print(company)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as this should do the trick.

```
email = "john.smith@apple.com".split('@')
username,domain= email[0],email[1].split('.')[0]
print(f'username: {username}\ndomain:{domain}')
```

broken down

simple break it down to ["john.smith","apple.com"]

username is first element in list

domain will take the second element in the list

split that element and take "apple" (first index)

```
email = "john.smith@apple.com".split('@')
username = email[0]
domain = email[1].split('.')[0]
print(f'username: {username}\ndomain:{domain}')
```

output

```
username: john.smith
domain:apple
```

Comment: My goal is to *not* print the "com" or "org", rather, the "apple" part of this example. How would I go about to do that without using .split() or .partition() ?

Comment: domain = email[1].split('.')[0] would return "apple" here